# Is it possible to load content of a file as variables in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Is it possible to add content of a file(import) as variables in another bash script? We can do this in python but not sure how its done in bash.

example conf file:

`server = xxxx`
`port = 8080`
`user = admin`

example script:

`echo "Hi $server"`